# EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN: Why is index not used?

Tags: sqlite, indexing

I am running a query which takes 2 seconds (much too long!) and returns 16 records:

```
SELECT * FROM cells WHERE cellbookguid='1' AND cellpageguid='1';
```

The table named "cells" holds around 20.000 records.
It has 42 columns such as "cellwidth, cellheight, cellcolor, cellbackground, cellpageguid, cellbookguid, etc.".

Because I don't understand why it takes so long, I run EXPLAIN QUERY.

It says:

```
order: 0
from: 0
detail: TABLE cells WITH INDEX idx_cells_cellbookguid
```

So obviously it does not use the index idx_cells_cellpageguid.
This must be why it takes so long.

However, this index is present:

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'index';"
```

It does contain "idx_cells_cellpageguid".

I have also used an external SQLite viewer. This index is present on the column.

Why does the SQLite query not use this index?

The definition of idx_cells_cellpageguid is

[image]

This is the SQL command:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_cells_cellpageguid
  ON cells
  (CellPageGUID COLLATE BINARY)
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the definition of idx_cells_cellpageguid?

Comment: @forpas I have added it to my post.

Comment: You should create a composite index that includes both columns cellbookguid and cellpageguid that appear in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @forpas How do I do that?

Comment: Like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=8c7acaf792cfd3263e030170450000a9

Comment: @forpas cellbookguid and cellpageguid are strings / text. Your example doesn't have to be changed because of that, right?

Comment: No, the syntax is the same.

Comment: Works amazingly!!! Can you make your comment the answer?